# How do I convert data from a list of lists to a readable table (or group of columns)?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

I have the following code that basically returns a list (`player1Hand`) of 5 lists (in this case, individual information about the cards in said hand).

```
def getPlayer2Hand(handAmount):
    getPlayer2Deck()
    player2Hand = []

    for i in range(handAmount):
        card = []
        card.append(deckListPlayer2Full[i]['NameOfCard'])
        card.append(deckListPlayer2Full[i]['Attack'])
        card.append(deckListPlayer2Full[i]['Defense'])
        card.append(deckListPlayer2Full[i]['Magic'])
        card.append(deckListPlayer2Full[i]['Shield'])
        player2Hand.append(card)

    return player2Hand
```

How do I print out the info in the list "`player2Hand"` into readable columns or a table? I would like to use the dict keys above (`NameOfCard`, `Attack`, etc.) as headers.

I tried to use TextTable, but I can't seem to get it to work.

Here is an example of what `player2Hand` looks like:

```
[['Knight', '500', '500', '0', '0'], 
['Mage', '0', '0', '500', '500'], 
['Mage', '0', '0', '500', '500'], 
['Mage', '0', '0', '500', '500'], 
['Mage', '0', '0', '500', '500']]
```

Comment: your question is not precise. what format do you need the table to be? anyway, have a look at [format string](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples)

Comment: Google **python format table**

Comment: Sorry for the lack of precision, but I was simply trying to print out the text from player1Hand\player2Hand into a series of columns with the headers above them. I found TextTable, which prints it into an ASCII style I think, but I haven't been able to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A bit string formatting might help:

```
>>> data = [['Knight', '500', '500', '0', '0'],
            ['Mage', '0', '0', '500', '500'],
            ['Mage', '0', '0', '500', '500'],
            ['Mage', '0', '0', '500', '500'],
            ['Mage', '0', '0', '500', '500']]

>>> frmt = '{:10s}' + 4 * '{:>12s}'
>>> for line in data::
        print(frmt.format(*line))
```

results in:

```
Knight             500         500           0           0
Mage                 0           0         500         500
Mage                 0           0         500         500
Mage                 0           0         500         500
Mage                 0           0         500         500
```

Comment: Do 10s and 12s represent "10 spaces" and "12 spaces", respectively?

Comment: Mike, thanks. I accepted this because it works almost exactly how I expected.

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick and dirty stab at what you may want to do:

```
>>> x = [['Knight', '500', '500', '0', '0'],['Mage', '0', '0', '500', '500'], ['Mage', '0', '0', '500', '500'], ['Mage', '0', '0', '500', '500'],  ['Mage', '0', '0', '500', '500']]
>>> for row in x:
...     output = [row[0].ljust(20)]
...     for col in row[1:]:
...         output.append(col.rjust(10))
...     print ''.join(output)
... 
Knight                     500       500         0         0
Mage                         0         0       500       500
Mage                         0         0       500       500
Mage                         0         0       500       500
Mage                         0         0       500       500
```